# How can I create a correctly signed distribution App Store build for a client without Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode5, ios-provisioning

I need to create a distribution App Store build for a client who doesn't have Xcode. Is there a way to do this without the client needing to give me credentials to their Apple Developer account?

I do see other questions that are similar,but a bit different, as they want the client to be able to re-sign on their end. Also, the questions are all a year or more older, and I'm hoping that this likely common situation has a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to be able to do is resign the code with their signing certificate then you can use a tool called iResign.  It would let you create a distribution build with one cert and then have it resigned with a different cert.  it's perfect for working with clients or providers who don't want to share credentials.

Comment: Very cool, found this on github, two different projects actually. I'll check them out, seems like this would be the ideal route to go.

Comment: COOL! I had not heard of this. That's a great idea, and solves the problem nicely (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a distribution build created with the client's credentials? Not possible unless the client gives you his credentials or sets you up with your own credentials as a member of his time.

Probably the cleanest way to do this is for the client to set you up as a team member on his team, issue you a certificate and a distribution provisioning profile, and then you build with that. I don't remember for sure if you have to be an admin to create a distribution build or not. I don't think so, but I'd have to check.

Comment: So once I create a build, they'd probably have to delete me from their team I'm guessing.

Comment: Well, being an ordinary team member only gives you very limited privileges. You can't create or delete apps, certificates, or provisioning profiles, and iTunes connect logins are completely separate.

Comment: As a team member you can really only build apps for which an admin has set you up in advance. It would probably  be easiest if your client set you up as a team member and left you that way, so you could submit updated builds later. That would only let you do the things that you are supposed to be doing, and so the risk to the client is minimal.

Comment: I am conflicted on which answer to accept as this one is probably the Apple prescribed way of handling things, while the iResign tool would seem to be the preferable method in terms of simplicity.

Comment: Accept the answer that's the most useful to you. I'm partial to Shadowman's answer. It's novel and useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Testflight. You just need the UDIDs of any devices that the client may test on. The app is then e-mailed out and the client can open and install.

Comment: Testflight is great for managing a group of testers, but the OP would still need to be able to build a distribution build of the app. For that he would need valid credentials for a member of the client's team. TestFlight also deals with Ad Hoc builds for testing. It isn't clear if the OP wants to deliver an Ad Hoc build for testing, or an app store build for submission to the app store/enterprise distribution

Comment: I edited my question to add App Store build. I am currently using TestFlight for testing builds.